# Insert pagebreak after \includepdf

Tags: page-breaking, pdfpages

I want to insert a page break after a pdf include this is what I have right now

```latex
\section{My Section}

Some text here!

\includepdf[pages=1-, scale=0.9, offset=0 -1]{my_pdf.pdf}
\newpage

\section{Another Section}
```

right now there is a the pages are:

```
Page1:
My Section (+ text)

Page2-5:
(my pdf)

Page6:
Another Section
```

But I wanted this:

```
Page1:
My Section (+ text)

Page2-5:
(my pdf)

Page6:
(empty page)

Page7:
Another Section
```

the command `\newpage` is there but it doesn't seem to work.
What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: use `\mbox{}\newpage`, or \cleardoublepage if you have a twoside document and want to get to the next odd page.

Comment: thank you so much!! it's works like a charm!
Please answer that so I can close the topic ;)